# Get url ? Read URL and use it in PHP file

Tags: php, url

Ok. I know that it is title is very confusing, but I do not know how to describe this..SOme tips ? :D

I want to create a page called , let's say -> category.php

On this page you see the parent categories. If a user clicks on this parent I need him go to category.php/parent_category.

On this page he or she sees the children of that specific parent - > And so on until the final page ( in my case a product ) is found.

I know this might sound simple, or maybe a dumb question but for me this is something I have never done before and after strolling on the internet en my LINDA courses I am still empty handed.

Hope someone can help me or lead the way a little bit.

Comment: I think you're looking for url rewriting http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/ - *"On this page you see the parent categories. If a user clicks on this parent I need him go to category.php/parent_category."* - Or, have I read it wrong? Or, "pagination" with search capabilities?

Comment: I feel stupid. This is exactly what I need. I dont see the V shaped figure to accept your answer.

Comment: That's because I didn't put in an "answer" per se ;)

Comment: Ok I understand. Well post is as an answer and claim your fortune my friend!

Comment: As per you wish Bas; it has been done. *Cheers* - You may have to wait a bit though. There's a 15 min. minimum time to accept.

Comment: You may not have been able to accept my answer earlier, since Stack imposes a 15 minute minimum before accepting an answer. You can do it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per OP's wish, comment to answer/answer: *(slightly modified)*

> *"On this page you see the parent categories. If a user clicks on this parent I need him go to category.php/parent_category."*

You're looking for url rewriting:

- **http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/**

...and click on the links at the bottom of the page for the continuation.

I.e.: **Go to page:** `1 | 2 | 3 | 4`

Example pulled from the said link:

If your application uses links like:

`http://www.downloadsite.com?category=34769845698752354`

then most of your visitors will find it difficult to get back to their favourite category (eg. Nettools/Messengers) every time they start from the main page of your site. Instead, they’d like to see URLs like this:

`http://www.downloadsite.com/Nettools/Messengers`

You can also consult the manual and extensive guide on Apache.org:

- **http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html**

which is done through `.htaccess`

Plus, if I read it wrong, "pagination" with search capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you usually do if you want make links that the user can save and use later, but not having to make specific pages for each of them would be to use get data with $_GET[]
That way you'll get links like "category.php?pc=this_category"
But if you specifically want links like category.php/parent_category you might need to rewrite it with .htaccess